# Exclude a radiobutton from .click() of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make and area on my page selectable, but inside there is a radiobutton which i dont want to be part of the selectable area. I have it setup at the moment to allow the user select the area but this also includes the radiobutton:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(document).on('click', 'label[title^="id_"]', function(e) {
        $(this).addClass('hide');
        var current = "s_" + $(this).attr('title');
        $("label[title='" + current + "']").removeClass('hide');
    });
});
```

This basic idea of the code at the moment is hide the selected div and show another. What i want is to exclude the radiobuttons inside this div from the click event.

I tried this: but it prevents clicking of the radiobuttons

```
if ($(e.target).is('input[type="radio"]')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
}
```

Comment: ...just remove `e.preventDefault()` and it should work. Why did you put it there in the first place?

Comment: `$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();return;});`

Comment: @blex: That's not going to do anything different than what the OP already has, disregarding that it will attach itself everywhere.

Comment: @Jon it seems to make a difference, check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wWX95/). Click on an area, it will be 'active', click on a radio button, the event is no longer propagated.

Comment: @blex: Yeah, that would happen after editing the comment to replace `return false` (or was it `e.preventDefault()`? I don't remember) with `e.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: @Jon oh ok, sorry, I edited my comment before seeing yours, so I thought you'd seen it.

Answer (score 0):

As said by [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50079/jon) in comments(and also my personal answer)

Your code should be:

```
if ($(e.target).is('input[type="radio"]')) {
    return;
}
```

Put that in opening of the function body of the click event handler.

The `return` call, will terminate the function so it wont progress further.

Comment: @user3793198 glad to have helped